# Rails Autocomplete with Ajax Find or create

Tags: jquery, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete

I am new to rails so please explain it like i'm a three year old :)

i cannot get this to trigger on autocompletion

view

```
 <div class="controls">
  <%= f.hidden_field :vehicle_id, :class => 'text_field', :id =>'veh_id' %>
  <%= f.autocomplete_field :vehicle_reg, autocomplete_vehicle_reg_number_vehicles_path, :id_element => '#veh_id', :class => 'text_field ui-autocomplete-input', :update_elements => {}  %>
</div>
```

java

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('Ready')
    $('#veh_id').bind('insertion-callback',
        function() {
            $('.autocomplete').bind('railsAutocomplete.select', function(event, data){
                console.log('Hello World')
                });

            });
    });
```

Comment: `what is the best` questions doesn't belongs to stack overflow. Also it is not allowed questions this broad. I suggest you to try yourself something, and if you can't make it work after working hard, post us your code and the error you can't solve, and someone will help you understand why you are having the error.

Comment: and got `+1` for the sportsmanship :-)